# Argument Specification in Functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to specify arguments into a function I've made:

I've got a function:

```
f(p, w, i, m)
```

p is a list of ints, w is an int, i is an int, m is a matrix (list of lists of ints). It returns a bool.

I've tried specifying this as:

```
f(p: List[int], w: int, i: int, m: list[int][int]) -> bool
```

But get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: Did you mean `List[List[int]]`?

Comment: Yes, this was it! Thanks, @tomerikoo

Comment: Happy to help, please mark the question as duplicate or delete it